# Activar notificación cuando la aplicación esta cerrada por completo

Tags: android, android-studio

Mi objetivo es que al presionar un botón, se espera por ejemplo 2 minutos, y me lance una notificación. El problema es que al bloquear la pantalla del teléfono, al cerrar la aplicación o al dejarla "minimizada", no me funciona, o sea no se me ejecuta nada, solo lo hace si tengo la aplicación en primer plano y con la pantalla del teléfono encendida. Esto lo hice usando la clase Timer y pasaba lo anterior. Ahora quiero intentarlo usando un Servicio pero mi duda es: Como lo hago?

```
  public void activarLuegoDeXtiempo(int a) { //metodo que se encarga de lanzar la notificación luego de X tiempo 
       //el valor de "a" lo introduce el usuario
       Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       c.setTime(date);
       c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,a*60000); //1s= 60000ms
       date = c.getTime();
       Timer time = new Timer();
       time.schedule(new Temporisador(), date);

   }
```

Esta es la clase que se en carga de ejecutar el Thread:

```
public class Temporisador extends TimerTask {


Thread myThread;
@Override
 public void run(){
         myThread= new MyTherad();
         myThread.start();
       }
}
```

Lanzo la notificación luego de X tiempo:
Clase  que hereda de Thread:

```
  @Override
public void run() {
 Activity_llamadas.getmInstanceActivity().activarNotificacion(); //activarNotificacion() método que construye una notificación y la muestra normalmente
}
```

Como hago para que cuando el teléfono este en reposo, con la pantalla apagada, se active la notificación, pero siempre luego de un tiempo (x), que compensara a contarse luego de haber presionado el botón.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para crear un **servicio** ([Documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=es-419)) te dejare la estructura básica de este. Con esto podrás ejecutar tareas en segundo plano.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class notificacion extends Service {

    public notificacion() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Servicio creado...");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Servicio iniciado...");

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Servicio destruido...");
    }


}
```

Dentro de la función `onStartCommand` añades lo que quieres que haga tu servicio en este caso crear la notificación. También es importante declarar tu servicio en el `Manifest`

```
 <service
        android:name=".notificacion"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
```